# 'at' or 'of' in a sentence

Tags: sentence-construction

> 1. No one believes him because he is false **at** heart.
> 2. No one believes him because he is false **of** heart.

Is the first statement wrong? What are the differences between 1) and 2)?

My book says 2) is the correct usage. But I have never seen anything like it until now.

Answer (score 4):

The first ("at heart") is more idiomatic; although the second ("of heart") is not wrong, and would probably be understood the same way.

One might also say

- "...because he is **false-hearted**.

Comment: ...........* **understood**

Comment: is "no one believes in him, because he is false at heart" correct?

Comment: I would add that "of heart" has a more formal, old-fashioned feel.  "The princess was pure of heart"

Answer (score 1):

Brian Hitchcock is right that both are possible and could be understood the same way.
Here are a couple of real examples:

**False at heart**:

> She said that he was false at heart,
> He called her light coquette :
> And both exclaimed--"next week we part,
> I wish we ne'er had met."
> <sub>—*[The New English Drama: With Prefactory Remarks, Biographical Sketches, and Notes, Critical and Explanatory](https://books.google.com/books?id=zBJFAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA18)*</sub>
> <sup>Volume 19, edited by William Oxberry.</sup>

**False of heart**:

> CIX.
>
> O, never say that I was false of heart,
> Though absence seem'd my flame to qualify.
> As easy might I from myself depart
> As from my soul, which in thy breast doth lie.
> <sub>—*[Shakespeare's Sonnets](https://archive.org/stream/Shakespearessonn01shak_201303/shakespearessonn01shak#page/n115/mode/2up)*, edited, with notes by William J. Rolfe. Litt.D., 1883.</sub>
> <sup>(The *Sonnets* were first published in 1609.)</sup>